# Kusto Go API query from multiple tables

Tags: go, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I'm using Kusto API to query logs from 2 tables, however they are in 2 different databases which are in different clusters and therefore have different endpoints (I can't modify the clusters). I would like to know if it's possible to use Kusto API to query logs from both tables

Comment: Why don't you simply use two clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regardless of which client library/tool you're using, and as long as you have read-permissions to both databases - you can include a reference to a database in a different cluster within the query text.

- the cluster you choose to run the query against will run the sub-query against the 2nd cluster.
- see: [Cross-cluster and cross-database queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/cross-cluster-or-database-queries?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

for example, run the following query on database `database1` on cluster `cluster1.westus`:

```
union withsource = T
   Table1, // this is in 'database1' in 'cluster1.westus'
   cluster("cluster2.westus2").database("database2").Table2,
   cluster("cluster2.centralus").database("database3").Table3
| where Timestamp > ago(1h)
| summarize count() by T
```

Comment: While this is true it does forcibly route the query through the cluster supplied at client creation time.